# Dialogflow follow-up intents not working? "Action" in training agent says "Not available."

Tags: facebook, loops, android-intent, dialogflow-es, chatbot

I'm trying to create a Facebook chatbot that only responds initially to each unique inquiry. I have about 25 intents with unique responses triggered by unique training phases. These are working fine.

However, I ran into the issue where the customer would continue chatting and the chatbot would continue responding. Basically, every time the customer sent something, the chatbot would respond, resulting in an infinite loop which frustrated the customer.

I saw a video that said creating a "follow-up intent" under the intent and setting the lifespan of the output context to 2 would solve the problem. I tested it with my default welcome message and it worked. For example, if the customer said "Hi," chatbot would respond "Hello." If again, the customer said hi in that same conversation, the chatbot would not respond.

HOWEVER. When I applied the follow-up intents to the other 24 intents, they did not work. Only the default welcome intent was working correctly. I set all the lifespans to 2, made sure to save, and even refreshed the page. In the training agent, I noticed the action for the working welcome message was "Fallback.Fallback-fallback" while the action for the non-working 24 other intents was "Not available."

Does anyone have a solution to this? Or an alternative solution to the issue of looping conversations?

Thank you.